# Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever

Tags: c++, pointers, static-cast, reinterpret-cast

Both `static_cast` and `reinterpret_cast` seem to work fine for casting `void*` to another pointer type. Is there a good reason to favor one over the other?

Comment: @anon Apparently you've never worked with POSIX threads before then.

Comment: @user470379 Wow...that's the very reason I landed on this question at SO!  Excellent observation :-).

Answer (score 214):

**Use `static_cast`**: it is the narrowest cast that exactly describes what conversion is made here.

There’s a misconception that using `reinterpret_cast` would be a better match because it means “completely ignore type safety and just cast from A to B”.

However, this doesn’t actually describe the effect of a `reinterpret_cast`. Rather, `reinterpret_cast` has a number of meanings, for all of which holds that “the mapping performed by `reinterpret_cast` is implementation-defined.” [5.2.10.3]

But in the particular case of casting from `void*` to `T*` the mapping is completely well-defined by the standard; namely, to assign a type to a typeless pointer without changing its address.

This is a reason to prefer `static_cast`.

Additionally, and arguably more important, is the fact that every use of `reinterpret_cast` is downright dangerous because it converts anything to anything else really (for pointers), while `static_cast` is much more restrictive, thus providing a better level of protection. This has already saved me from bugs where I accidentally tried to coerce one pointer type into another.

Answer (score 71):

The `static_cast` is more appropriate for converting a `void*` to a pointer of some other type.

`static_cast` is the cast of choice when there is a natural, intuitive conversion between two types that isn't necessarily guaranteed to work at runtime.  For example, you can use `static_cast` to convert base class pointers to derived class pointers, which is a conversion that makes sense in some cases but can't be verified until runtime.  Similarly, you can use `static_cast` to convert from an `int` to a `char`, which is well-defined but may cause a loss of precision when executed.

`reinterpret_cast`, on the other hand, is a casting operator designed to do conversions that are fundamentally not safe or not portable.  For example, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to convert from a `void *` to an `int`, which will work correctly if your system happens to have `sizeof (void*)` ≤ `sizeof (int)`.  You can also use `reinterpret_cast` to convert a `float*` to an `int*` or vice-versa, which is platform-specific because the particular representations of `float`s and `int`s aren't guaranteed to have anything in common with one another.

In short, if you ever find yourself doing a conversion in which the cast is logically meaningful but might not necessarily succeed at runtime, avoid `reinterpret_cast`.  `static_cast` is a good choice if you have some advance knowledge that the cast is going to work at runtime, and communicates to the compiler "I know that this might not work, but at least it makes sense and I have a reason to believe it will correctly do the right thing at runtime."  The compiler can then check that the cast is between related types, reporting a compile-time error if this isn't the case.  Using `reinterpret_cast` to do this with pointer conversions completely bypasses the compile-time safety check.

There are a few circumstances where you might want to use a `dynamic_cast` instead of a `static_cast`, but these mostly involve casts in a class hierarchy and (only rarely) directly concern `void*`.

As for which one is preferred by the spec, neither is overly mentioned as "the right one to use" (or at least, I don't remember one of them being mentioned this way.)  However, I think the spec wants you to use `static_cast` over `reinterpret_cast`.  For example, when using a C-style cast, as in

```
A* ptr = (A*) myVoidPointer;
```

The order of casting operators that's tried always tries to use a `static_cast` before a `reinterpret_cast`, which is the behavior you want since `reinterpret_cast` isn't guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: To clarify: what the author means here by "`static_cast`... isn't necessarily guaranteed to work at runtime" is, "Your program may crash later on." If you `static_cast` from a base type to a derived type, it **will** "work" at runtime (i.e. you will **not** get an exception or a `NULL` pointer), but the result may be pointing to the wrong memory location if multiple inheritance is involved. (See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7789468/266704) for more details.) Only `dynamic_cast` will do a runtime check (using RTTI) and fail gracefully if the cast is invalid.

Answer (score 12):

This is a tough question. On the one hand, Konrad makes an excellent point about the spec definition for **reinterpret_cast**, although in practice it probably does the same thing. On the other hand, if you're casting between pointer types (as is fairly common when indexing in memory via a char*, for example), **static_cast** will generate a compiler error and you'll be forced to use **reinterpret_cast** anyway.

In practice I use **reinterpret_cast** because it's more descriptive of the intent of the cast operation. You could certainly make a case for a different operator to designate pointer reinterprets only (which guaranteed the same address returned), but there isn't one in the standard.

Comment: "_different operator to designate pointer reinterprets only (which guaranteed the same address returned)_" Hug? That operator **is** `reinterpret_cast`!

Comment: @curiousguy Not true according to the standard. reinterpret_cast does NOT guarantee that the same address is used. Only that if you reinterpret_cast from one type to another *and then back again*, you will get back the same address you started with.

Answer (score 3):

You likely obtained that `void*` with implicit conversion, so you should use `static_cast` because it is closest to the implicit conversion.

Answer (score 3):

There's confusion about implementation defined mappings. That is about *mappings*. The implementation can internally map however it likes, but it must make other guarantees otherwise. A result of reinterpret_cast can't simply arbitrarily point to what the implementation would otherwise consider some other object's location -- though the *outward representation* may differ. (Though converting to integer and back will have original value, in specific circumstances, outlined). **Fundamentally, it's irrelevant whether the implementation's reinterpreted cast returns the same "memory location"; whatever it returns is mapped to the same "value"**. (Incidentally, [The core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun) explicitly answer a case where using reinterpret_cast (char*/unsigned char*/std::byte*) to view raw object representation is defined behavior.)

Relevant standards rules the void* cast:

**static_cast**:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 void” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T”, where T is
> an object type and cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. If the original
> pointer value represents the address A of a byte in memory and A does not satisfy the alignment requirement
> of T, then the resulting pointer value is unspecified. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an
> object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible (6.8.3)
> with a, the result is a pointer to b. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.
> [Example 3 :
> `T* p1 = new T; const T* p2 = static_cast<const T*>(static_cast<void*>(p1)); bool b = p1 == p2; // b will have the value true.`
> —end example]

**reintrepret_cast**:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.68 When a prvalue v of
> object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to cv T”, the result is **`static_cast<cv T*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`**

The key is the last sentence. For the purposes of this question's void* cast, (and assuming object types meet alignment requirements, cv qualifications, and are safefly-derived pointers):

`reinterpret_cast T* from void*`
is equivalent to
`static_cast T* from void*`.

But you should definitely, definitely absolutely definitely use `static_cast` for no other reason that the scary folklore about reinterpret_cast and convolutedness of the ISO standard may lead to get you needlessly harangued by peers.

https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ru-pun

Answer (score 2):

Casting to and from `void*` using `static_cast` and using `reinterpret_cast` is identical. See the answer at [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68137312/5447906). But usually `static_cast` is preferred because it is more narrow and in general (but not in this specific case) more safe conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the weakest possible cast always.

`reinterpret_cast` may be used to cast a pointer to a `float`. The more structure-breaking the cast is, the more attention using it requires.

In case of `char*`, I'd use c-style cast, until we have some `reinterpret_pointer_cast`, because it's weaker and nothing else is sufficient.

Comment: "_reinterpret_cast is may be used to cast a pointer to a float._" Certainly not!

Comment: certainly yes, curiousguy. Check the standard again.

Comment: "_Check the standard again._" Have _you_ checked the standard?

Comment: Yes. Not sure what you mean by example though - the only intended use for that would be forwarding a float thru a pointer-expecting cookie.

Comment: How do you cast a pointer to a float? `void* p = 0; float f = reinterpret_cast<float>(p);` generates `error: invalid cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘float’`. I can cast to int, but not float.

Comment: Probably `float f = *reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&p);`

Comment: @BenVoigt That is casting between pointers; one of them happened to be a float pointer.

Comment: @nodakai: Nope, it reinterprets the bits of `p` as a `float`.  A pointer to `p` is used to accomplish this, but `p` is coerced to `float` not `float*`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That `reinterpret_cast` is casting from some pointer (whatever `p` is) to a `const float*`.  That pointer is then dereferenced to get the float value.  This does result in the bit representation of `p` being used as a `float`, but the `reinterpret_cast` itself is still casting a pointer type to a different pointer type.

Comment: @cemafor no not from whatever p is to `float*`.  From "pointer to what p is" - a double pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sorry, I meant the type the `reinterpret_cast` is casting is a pointer to whatever type `p` is. If `p` is a `double`, it would be casting from a `double*` to a `const float*`. The type of `&p` is a `double*`.

Comment: @BenVoigt the `*` before `reinterpret_cast` is not part of the cast. It is a deference operator replied to the result of the cast. In this code `reinterpret_cast` converts a pointer to a pointer.   Then the latter pointer is dereferenced, after the cast is complete.

Comment: @M.M: I know that `*` is a separate operator, but my comment is still correct.  Did you overlook the additional `&` in the operand of `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't overlook it, and your comment is wrong. `reinterpret_cast<const float *>(&p)` converts a pointer to a pointer. The content of the `< >` is the result type of the cast.

Comment: Then, the unary dereference operator is applied to the result of the cast.  The `*` operator converts `const float *` to `float` (the cast operator does not convert to `float`)

Comment: @M.M: The entire expression taken together, `*reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&p)`, does coerce `p` to `float`.  My comment is not wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt the "entire expression" isn't a cast though. The expression consists of a dereference applied to a cast. You claimed that it was possible to cast a pointer to `float`, which is false. The expression casts `void **` to `const float *`, and then uses a dereference operation (which is NOT a cast), to convert `const float *` to `float`.

Comment: @M.M: Indeed it's not a cast.  I never called it one.

Comment: @BenVoigt you offered that code in response to someone asking "How do I cast...", and then when someone said that the code casts between pointers (which it does), you said "Nope"

Comment: @M.M: I presumed that the person asking may have said "cast" but wanted a conversion that wasn't a direct cast.  And then another user claimed it cast a `void*` to a `float*`, which was wrong.  It cast a `void**` to a `float*`, to convert a `void*` to a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `static_cast` for this. Only in the rarest of rare cases when there is no other way use `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score -3):

`reinterpret_cast` will forcefully convert the `void*` to the target data type. It doesn't guarantee any safety and your program might crash as the underlying object could be anything.

For ex, you could typecast an `myclass*` to `void*` and then use `reinterpret_cast` to convert it to `yourclass*` which may have a completely different layout.

So its better and recommended to use `static_cast`

Comment: static_cast will not prevent this from happening. Once a pointer has degenerated into a void* you can static_cast it to any type of pointer.