# static method with polymorphism in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, static-methods, non-static

I have a weird issue using polymorphism.
I have a base class that implements a static method. This method must be static for various reasons. The base class also has a pure virtual method `run()` that gets implemented by all the extended classes. I need to be able to call `run()` from the static class.

The problem, of course, is that the static class doesn't have a this pointer. This method can be passed in a void * parameter. I have been trying to come up with a clever way to pass the run method into it, but nothing has worked so far. have also tried passing this into it. The problem with this is that I would then have to instantiate it, which requires knowledge of the extended class. This defeats the whole purpose of the polymorphism.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: I think you mean "static method" last in the first paragraph?

Comment: Ori, you object to passing `this` to the static method because "I would then have to instantiate it," but you want to call the virtual `run` method. You can't call a virtual method without an instance, so you would have to instantiate the class anyway. The static method doesn't need to know *which* class was instantiated; it's just receiving a base-class pointer, as Chris's answer demonstrates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't pass it as a void* pointer, pass it as a pointer (or reference) to the base class:

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
  static void something(BaseClass* self) { self->foo(); }
  virtual void foo() = 0;  
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens when you have to squirrel your C++ objects through a C API. A classic example is a thread class.

Here's the standard idiom for doing this:

```
/** calls thread_func in a new thread passing it user_data as argument */
thrd_hdl_t c_api_thread_start(int (*thread_func)(void*), void* user_data);

/** abstract thread base class
* override my_thread::run to do work in another thread
*/
class my_thread {
  public:
    my_thread() hdl_(c_api_thread_start(my_thread::thread_runner,this)) {}
    // ...

  private:
    virtual int run() = 0; // we don't want this to be called from others

    thrd_hdl_t hdl_; // whatever the C threading API uses as a thread handle

    static int thread_runner(void* user_data)
    {
      my_thread* that = static_cast<my_thread*>(user_data);
      try {
        return that->run();
      } catch(...) {
        return oh_my_an_unknown_error;
      }
    }
};
```

Would that help?

Comment: nice snippet, but isn't it better to use `static_cast` to cast from `void*` to another pointer?

Comment: @Eli: Oops. Can you do that? I didn't know. If you're sure, I'll certainly change it. (Feel free make the change yourself.)

Comment: you certainly *can* do that (since `void*` is statically cast-able to any pointer). But whether you want to is really a matter of good practice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever    Since it's your answer I'll let you decide :)

Comment: @Eli: Thanks, that's an interesting discussion. FWIW, I changed my answer. Thank you for pointing out this issue!

Answer (score 3):

Why not pass a reference to the object in rather than the method e.g.

```
static void func( BaseObject& o)
{
     o.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, your best bet is to get rid of the static method. Find a way around *that* and you're golden.