# C++ static_cast from float** to void**

Tags: c++

Just ran into this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float *a = new float[10];
    void **b;
    b = static_cast<void**>(&a);
    delete(a); 
    return 0;
}

macbook:C nils$ g++ -Wall -g -o static_cast static_cast.cpp 
static_cast.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
static_cast.cpp:9: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘float**’ to type ‘void**’
macbook:C nils$ clang++ -Wall -g -o static_cast static_cast.cpp 
static_cast.cpp:9:9: error: static_cast from 'float **' to 'void **' is not
      allowed
    b = static_cast<void**>(&a);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
macbook:C nils$
```

Why is it not allowed? While b = (void**)(&a); works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$5.2.9/2 -

> "An expression e can be explicitly
>   converted to a type T using a
>   static_cast of the form
>   static_cast(e) if the declaration
>   “T t(e);” is well-formed, for some
>   invented temporary variable t (8.5).
>   The effect of such an explicit
>   conversion is the same as performing
>   the declaration and initialization and
>   then using the temporary variable as
>   the result of the conversion. The
>   result is an lvalue if T is a
>   reference type (8.3.2), and an rvalue
>   otherwise. The expression e is used as
>   an lvalue if and only if the
>   initialization uses it as an lvalue."

Let us take the case of Code snippet 1 as below

`float *f;`

`void *p = f;`

Here initialization of 'p' is well-formed. This is in accordance with $4.2

`An rvalue of type “pointer to cv T,” where T is an object type, can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to cv void.”`

Now let us take the code in OP

In our case, 'E' is `'float **'` and 'T' is `'void **'`

So, whether static_cast will work for the attempted conversion if 'p' can be initialized as shown below

`float **f;`

`void **p = f;`

The initialization of 'p' is ill-formed as it is not a valid condition listed under `$4.10`

Now, coming to why `b = (void**)(&a);` works?

This is the case where an explicit cast is used (`$5.4`). In this case, this explicit cast is equivalent of `reinterpret_cast` (`$5.4/5`). In this particular case, this conversion is allowed (`$5.2.1/7`).

Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

See [Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever).

you should use [reinterpret_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b(VS.80).aspx).

I've used static cast to cast from a child class to the parent class, or where I knew the the type conversion was safe. If I needed runt time verification, then I'd use dynamic_cast.

Comment: static_cast isn't for casting child classes to parent classes - that's an implicit conversion that doesn't require casting at all.

Comment: dynamic_cast is used for safe casts down or across an inheritance hierarchy. At least that's what I read in Scott Meyers book.

Answer (score 1):

When you write C-style to cast you basically are circumventing the C++ type checks
so that is very "forgiving". However in order to conform to C++ (and to be on the safe side) you should use the C++ casts static_cast,dynamic_cast or reinterpret_cast.

reinterpret_cast is the closest you can get in C++ to a C-cast without actually doing C-cast.

Comment: "reinterpret_cast is the closest you can get in C++ to a C-cast without actually doing C-cast." - So everything which works with a c-style cast should work with reinterpret_cast?

Comment: not 100% no. e.g. long a= 1; double b = (double)a; works but double c = reinterpret_cast<double>(a); doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want a `void**`, but rather `void*`, for the reason mentioned by Joe Gauterin in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625410/c-static-cast-from-float-to-void/3625428#3625428)

Comment: No I want void** http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_0/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gc63ffd93e344b939d6399199d8b12fef.html#gc63ffd93e344b939d6399199d8b12fef