# pin_ptr Alternative to (void**) using reinterpret_cast or static_cast?

Tags: c++-cli

Is there an alternative to using the following?

```
class IGraphBuilder;

public ref class Device
{
private:
    IGraphBuilder* pGraphBuilder;

public:
    void Configure()
    {
        pin_ptr<IGraphBuilder*> ppGraphBuilder = &pGraphBuilder;

        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC,
            IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)ppGraphBuilder);
```

reinterpret_cast(ppGraphBuilder) compiles but I'm a bit confused if this is correct for this case.

If this wasn't C++/CLI (where `&NativeMember` actually means `interior_ptr<Type>(NativeMember)`) I would simply use `static_cast<void**>(&pGraphBuilder)` but even after correctly casting to `pin_ptr` the following doesn't compile

```
pin_ptr<IGraphBuilder*> ppGraphBuilder = &pGraphBuilder;
static_cast<void**>(ppGraphBuilder)
```

Is there any solution or am I forced to use (void**) because pin_ptr is weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` (and thus C cast) is potentially not ok, although it may work due to the allegedly trivial layout of `pin_ptr`. Indeed you have to call the conversion operator from `cli::pin_ptr<IGraphBuilder*>` to `IGraphBuilder**` first (hence the complain from the compiler).

```
reinterpret_cast<void**>(static_cast<IGraphBuilder**>(ppGraphBuilder))
```

is correct. You may want to introduce a intermediary variable of type `IGraphBuilder**` first:

```
pin_ptr<IGraphBuilder*> p = &pGraphBuilder;
IGraphBuilder** ppGraphBuilder = p;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC,
        IID_IGraphBuilder, reinterpret_cast<void**>(p));
```

Comment: Doing that errors in `C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'IGraphBuilder **' to 'void **'` This thread talks about the same issue... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625410/c-static-cast-from-float-to-void/

Comment: @NtscCobalt: You're right. One has to use `reinterpret_cast` for the second cast. This does not change the fact that technically, you need two conversions.

Comment: is `reinterpret_cast<void**>` in that case safe to use after first casting to `IGraphBuilder**`?

Comment: @NtscCobalt: Yes, otherwise you would never be able to do COM.

Comment: @Alaxandre C. ah ok thank you. Casting using the C style `(void**)` does work and is currently in place `(void**)pin_ptr<IGraphBuilder*>(&pGraphBuilder)`. I will change all of my C++/CLI COM calls to look like your post now for readability and safety. Thanks.