# Increment void pointer by one byte? by two?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I have a void pointer called `ptr`.  I want to increment this value by a number of bytes.  Is there a way to do this?

Please note that I want to do this in-place without creating any more variables.

Could I do something like `ptr = (void *)(++((char *) ptr));` ?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You cannot perform arithmetic on a void pointer because pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the size of the pointed-to object.

You can, however, cast the pointer to a `char*`, do arithmetic on that pointer, and then convert it back to a `void*`:

```
void* p = /* get a pointer somehow */;

// In C++:
p = static_cast<char*>(p) + 1;

// In C:
p = (char*)p + 1;
```

Comment: shouldn't that be reinterpret_cast?

Comment: @Balk:  `static_cast` is sufficient.

Comment: I'm getting `invalid type conversion` error when converting `MyStruct*` to `char*` using the method in this answer. Is there some context missing?

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica - yes: you are not casting a `void*` to any other pointer type (which can be done statically) but `MyStruct*` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310489)

Answer (score 28):

No arithmeatic operations can be done on `void` pointer.

The compiler doesn't know the size of the item(s) the `void` pointer is pointing to. You can cast the pointer to (`char *`) to do so.

In gcc there is an extension which treats the size of a `void` as `1`. so one  can use arithematic on a `void*` to add an offset in bytes, but using it would yield non-portable code.

Comment: In GCC it's possible because `sizeof(void)` yields `1`.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: It is extension in GCC which treats the size of a void as 1,  Using it would yield non-portable code.

Comment: @Blag: As always, please compile with `-pedantic`. :)

Comment: With `-Wpedantic`, as suggested by @Xeo, I got a new `warning: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]`. Solved by casting (to `uint8_t` in my case which I'm using for bytes).

Answer (score 8):

Just incrementing the `void*` does happen to work in gcc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i[] = { 23, 42 };
    void* a = &i;
    void* b = a + 4;
    printf("%i\n", *((int*)b));
    return 0;
}
```

It's conceptually (and officially) wrong though, so you want to make it explicit: cast it to `char*` and then back.

```
void* a = get_me_a_pointer();
void* b = (void*)((char*)a + some_number);
```

This makes it obvious that you're increasing by a number of bytes.

Comment: As always, please compile with `-pedantic`. :) It's a non-conforming extension by GCC.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
++(*((char **)(&ptr)));
```

Comment: Yeah, but why _would_ you? That's horrible obscure code that makes it needlessly difficult to parse what it's doing, for no good reason. Also, C-style casts are to be discouraged in C++, but that's the least of the problems here.

Comment: You can also shove a flaming stick into your eye.  It would probably hurt less than looking at `++(*((char **)(&ptr)));`.

Comment: He wanted to do this in-place without creating any more variables, so I gave this solution. You can see it as an instructional way, but definitely not for using it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, arithmetic on void pointers should not be allowed at all as the size of the data type is not available.

But some compilers like the GCC assume void to be of size 1 byte and a increment on a void pointer x will be equivalent to x + 1.

To confirm this, I wrote a small program which is as follows

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int x = 10;
  void* y = (void*) &x;
  cout<<y<<endl;
  void *z = y;
  z++;
  cout<<(z)<<endl;
  cout<<(y+1)<<endl;
}
```

And the output is as follows
[You can](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bzMv.png)

But GCC does give warnings while compiling
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUJbP.png)