# C void pointer arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

I thought that in gcc, void * and char * are treated the same way when it comes to pointer arithmetic, i.e. void * "points" to a single byte in memory, so the following code

```
void *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(void));
printf("%p %p\n",p,p+1);
```

indeed returns `0x984a008 0x984a009`. Similarly, void ** points to a pointer, so an increment by one really means an increment by 4 bytes (on a 32 bit OS), i.e.

```
void **p;
p = (void **) malloc(sizeof(void *));
printf("%p %p\n",p,p+1);
```

returns `0x984a008 0x984a00c`. However, the following code confuses me

```
void **p, *p1;
p = (void **) malloc(sizeof(void *));
p1 = (void **) p;
printf("%p %p\n",p1,p1+1);
```

Since it returns again `0x984a008 0x984a009`. What is going on here?

Comment: Perhaps you meant to type `void **p, **p1;` instead of `void **p, *p1;` ?

Comment: `sizeof(void)` is 1 or at least gives a warning, it's useless. You don't do that.  What does a `void` type indicate?? there's only `void*`.

Comment: I did mean void **p, *p1. I know this code compiles, what I don;t understand is why if p is originally declared as void **, p+1 corresponds to an increment by 4 bytes, while if p1 is declared void * and later recast as void **, the arithmetic only adds 1 byte for p1+1

Comment: Why is that, is the cast to `void **` ignored?

Comment: @Ivan: Yes, obviously it's ignored.  It's an identity cast (the expression `p` already had type `void**`).  Identity casts are ignored except for some effect on value category (e.g. the result of the cast is an rvalue)

Answer (score 7):

Ignoring the possible undefined behaviour of `void` pointer arithmetic for the moment...

The type of `p1` is `void *`.

You can't change a variable's type by assigning a value of a different type to it. `p1` will always stay `void *`.

Any expression of a different type assigned to it will implicitly be cast to `void *` (or give an error if it can not).

Thus it's essentially the same as the first example.

**EDIT:**

As far as I know, casting from one pointer type to another doesn't actually do anything, its main purpose is for type-checking.

A pointer is just a memory address, a number, so essentially the memory looks something like: (post-assignment)

```
  p1       p2
void *   void** <- these types are fixed and known during compilation
------   ------
|1234|   |1234|         at address 1234 = the 4 bytes from malloc
------   ------
  ^
  |
this value is the only thing that will change by assigning p1 to a different value
```

Comment: On some architectures, casting from one pointer type to another does change something. On your typical x86(_64) architecture, though, you can expect all pointers to have the same representation and casts being a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `char *` instead of `void *`, since arithmetic on pointer to `void` is a gcc extension.

```
char *p1 = /* ... */;

printf("%p %p\n", p1, p1+1);
```

Whatever points `p`, the pointer arithmetic on `p` uses `char *` type (not `char **`).

If you write:

```
char *p1 = /* ... */;

printf("%p %p\n", p1, (char**)p1+1);
```

Pointer arithmetic uses `char **`.

Answer (score 2):

When you operate with `void *`, the increment is 1. When you use `void **`, it's the size of a pointer.

In the operation that confuses you, your `void *` cast to `void **` is being implicitly made back into a `void *`. It's as if you did this:

```
long a, b, c;
c = a + (int) b;
```

You cast `b` to `int`, but then you want to operate with a `long`, so it's cast back.

Comment: That's fine, but why does the compiler do the recast back? Both `void *` and `void **` take 4 bytes on the stack and as far as I understand all the pointer arithmetic is done at compile time. So why does the compiler insist that p1 is cast back?

Comment: Think of it this way: it makes sense to cast `void **` to `void *` -- any pointer can become `void *`. Casting the other way round, on the other hand, dose not. Not all pointers are double pointers. The compiler does the sensitive thing with the operation you requested: it makes sense of it the only way it can.

Answer (score 1):

The void pointer can not be incremented. It is undefined behavior.

Related question: 
[Increment void pointer by one byte? by two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449935/increment-void-pointer-by-one-byte-by-two)

Comment: OK, but if you change all the types to `char` pointers the question still stands (although GCC will give you a warning in that case)

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm posting over a year later, but I happened upon this question and it intrigued me.

I agree with @Dukeling that you can't change a variable's type just by casting it.  But it seems it depends upon what the compiler deems `void` to be.  Take this example program, and look at the resulting output.  Notice that the only difference between `vp` and `vp2` is the `sizeof()` portion of the `malloc()`.

Compiled on: `gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`
Compile line: `gcc -o void_test void_test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void *vp, *vp2;

  printf("sizeof(void)   = %d\n", sizeof(void));
  printf("sizeof(void *) = %d\n", sizeof(void *));
  printf("sizeof(char)   = %d\n", sizeof(char));
  printf("sizeof(char *) = %d\n\n", sizeof(char *));

  vp = (void *) malloc(sizeof(void));
  vp2 = (void *) malloc(sizeof(void *));

  printf("vp    = %p\n", vp);
  printf("vp+1  = %p\n", vp+1);
  printf("vp2   = %p\n", vp);
  printf("vp2+1 = %p\n", vp2+1);

  return 0;
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
$ ./void_test 
sizeof(void)   = 1
sizeof(void *) = 8
sizeof(char)   = 1
sizeof(char *) = 8

vp    = 0x1ee3010
vp+1  = 0x1ee3011
vp2   = 0x1ee3010
vp2+1 = 0x1ee3031
```