# Do I need to typecast the void pointer again for the arithmetics after its been casted for the copy?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

when doing that code:

```
void    *ft_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    void    *orgdest;

    orgdest = dest;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        *(unsigned char *)dest = *(unsigned char *)src;
        n--;
        dest++;
        src++;
    }
    return (orgdest);
}
```

the *void* pointer has been typecasted to *unsigned char** to copy from src to dest.
Then I use the pointers inside the while loop **(dest++; src++;)**. Should I cast them again for the arithmetics (as they were void*, and cant be used for arithmetics) like **dest = ((unsigned char *)dest + 1)**; or are they already casted to the unsigned char type and can be used?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you typecasted the address in the function instead of having the input pointer in the desired type? I don't think that's a good practice to do that

Comment: its an academic exercise, required to have a prototype like this. I wonder if I have to cast it twice

Comment: @MichaelTeguhLaksana It’s common practice to use `void*` for generic pointers. The function will obviously be called with pointers to various types, not just `unsigned char`. Using `void*` parameters means that the *caller* doesn’t have to cast.

Comment: Since this is a naive copy algorithm you might as well toss the whole thing out the window and write `unsigned char* d = dest;
unsigned char* s = src;

for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  d[i] = s[i];
}`. It should be equivalent, but with some luck it might even be more cache-friendly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, I see. Thanks for the information. I have never seen such thing done and  I always pass the pointer with the desired type, so I'm kind of surprised with such practice. So does this mean we can put any type of variable when the function is called as an argument?

Comment: @MichaelTeguhLaksana Any type of *pointer*. And I’m sure you’ve seen this already, it’s used pervasively by the C standard library itself (`memcpy` does it, for instance) as well as operating system libraries (POSIX, Win32).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to cast the pointers as [arithmetic on `void *` pointers is illegal in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c).  Note that the increment is *also* not proper syntax, so you'd need to do

```
void    *ft_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    void    *orgdest;

    orgdest = dest;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        *(unsigned char *)dest = *(unsigned char *)src;
        n--;
        dest = ( unsigned char * ) dest + 1;
        src = ( unsigned char * ) src + 1;
    }
    return (orgdest);
}
```

Note that creating local copies of `unsigned char *` type is easier to understand:

```
void    *ft_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    const unsigned char *local_src = src;
    unsigned char *local_dest = dest;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        *local_dest = *local_src;
        n--;
        local_dest++;
        local_src++;
    }
    return (dest);
}
```

Comment: @rpunet A cast does not modify the variable you’re casting in any way. It creates a *new value* and returns that. Casting `src` does not modify `src`, and especially not *its type*: that stays `void*`, and there’s nothing you can do to change that.

Comment: @rpunet In your original code, the casts for the copy in `*(unsigned char *)dest = *(unsigned char *)src;` do not persist/carry over to the `dest++;` or `src++;` increment statements.

Comment: @rpunet Arithmetic on `void *` pointers is allowed as an extension by GCC, so a lot of C (and C++) programmers don't know that it's a syntax violation.

Comment: `( unsigned char * ) dest` isn't a lvalue so you can't do ++ on it. Use temporary variables as in the second example.

Comment: @Lundin  Yep.  I forgot that's also a GCCism - I never do the first.  [My comment on something like this was three years ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131830/4756299)

Comment: gnu11 considered harmful.