# How to properly copy complex numbers from a vector of vectors to GPU device memory and perform FFT using CUDA?

Tags: c++, windows, cuda, fft

I'm working on a C++ Windows project that involves FFT calculations on devices using the CUDA 10.1 library.
I have a vector of vectors `std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<float>>> unitedVector` and I need to copy its contents to device memory to perform FFT on the GPU.
I have a `std::complex<float>* gpu_data` pointer that points to allocated memory on the device using `cudaMalloc`.

To initialize the cuFFT plan I use the following code:

```
cufftHandle plan;
int data_size = unitedVector[0].size();  // Size of data in each vector
int num_channels = unitedVector.size();  // Number of vectors (or channels with data)
std::complex<float>* gpu_data;

cufftPlan1d(&plan, data_size, CUFFT_C2C, num_channels); // Create FFT plan
cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_data, num_channels * data_size * sizeof(std::complex<float>)); // Allocation of memory on the GPU
```

After the plan is initialized, I copy the data like this:

```
cudaMemcpy(gpu_data, unitedVector[0].data(), num_channels * data_size * sizeof(std::complex<float>), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Next, I perform FFT as follows:

```
cufftResult result = cufftExecC2C(plan, reinterpret_cast<cufftComplex*>(gpu_data), reinterpret_cast<cufftComplex*>(gpu_data), CUFFT_FORWARD);

// Rotate the spectrum (fftshift)
int half_size = data_size / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_channels; ++i) {
        cudaMemcpy(unitedVector[i].data(), gpu_data + i * data_size + half_size, half_size * sizeof(std::complex<float>), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(unitedVector[i].data() + half_size, gpu_data + i * data_size, half_size * sizeof(std::complex<float>), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }

// unitedVector now contains the FFT results for each vector
```

My FFT implementation runs on the device and uses the cuFFT library for this purpose.

Question: How can I copy data from unitedVector to gpu_data correctly, and how can I do FFT for each vector on the device using CUDA? Could you provide example code for this task?

I used the code above to copy the data and do the FFT. However, I am having problems with the FFT results: The first 3-4 times the FFT is calculated correctly (as in Matlab) and then an exception occurs. I suspect that the problem may be with a bad copy of the data or with my FFT implementation. How can I fix this situation?

Comment: I strongly suggest you don’t use a vector of vectors for a 2D array. If each of the inner vectors is of a different size, you might not have another option. But if they’re all the same size (2D array), it will be a lot more efficient (and easier!) to store it in a single memory block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping over the inner vectors, doing one `cudaMemcpy` per block of memory:

```
int n_bytes = data_size * sizeof(std::complex<float>);
cudaError_t status;
for (int i = 0; i < num_channels; ++i) {
  auto to   = gpu_data + i * data_size;
  auto from = unitedVector[i].data();
  status = cudaMemcpy((void *)to, (void *)from, (size_t)n_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  if (status != cudaSuccess)
    std::cout<<"CudaMemcpy failed!"<<std::endl;;
}
```

Comment: I did not compile and run the code snippet. If there is any syntax error you can always mention it for editing!

Comment: What do the casts achieve when `cudaMemcpy` takes `void *` anyway? Seems like an unnecesary step to me.

Comment: I did cast to `float *` for the arithmetic operations for calculating the addresses. It is not possible to perform these on `void *` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449935/increment-void-pointer-by-one-byte-by-two). Also, I prioritized intuitiveness, thus, tried to make it as explicit as possible.

Comment: I guess I just don't see how this is more intuitive than `auto to = gpu_data + i * data_size;`. The `complex<float> *` should do the arithmetic fine.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It wasn't really part of the arithmetic, but I took the freedom to adapt the rest of the answer to the change as the text was also still talking about `reinterpret_cast`...