# Cast member function for create_pthread() call

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I want to stop the warning

> server.cpp:823: warning: converting from 'void* (ClientHandler::*)()' to 'void* (*)(void*)'

in the call:

```
pthread_create(th, NULL,
    (void* (*)(void*)) &ClientHandler::handle,
    (void *) clientHandler);
```

where `handle()` is a member function of `ClientHandler`:

```
void* ClientHandler::handle();
```

I have difficulties deciphering the function-type message from the compiler.

The question is:

- **Should I change the `handle()` interface?** Can I get rid of casting overall?
- **Should I change the cast?** To what exactly?
- Something completely different?

Comment: You should not pass pointer to a member function instead of function pointer.

Comment: Can you make `ClientHandler::handle` static ?

Comment: @sander: no, I need the `this` pointer to access the instances data members in the callback. Of course, I could pass that one explicitly to a static function.

Comment: @towi: in your original question, you're basically asking about interactions between `C` callbacks and member functions. Your updated questions regard details of the STL - completely unrelated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that directly, pointers to member functions are not plain pointers to functions and can't be handed over to `C` callbacks directly.

You'll need one level of indirection:

```
void callHandle(void *data) {
  ClientHandle *h = static_cast<ClientHandle*>(data);
  h->handle();
}

pthread_create(th, 0, &callHandle, static_cast<void*>(handle));
```

See the [Pointers to members](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) section of the C++FAQ for more information / alternatives.

For the validity of the cast in `callHandle`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever). You are sole responsible for making sure that `handle` is still alive and well when `callHandle` is called of course (and for the fact that it actually points to a `ClientHandle`).

Comment: whooo... I see. actually, it *does* work, but I guess only by accident. Probably non-portable.

Comment: I don't think there is any accident there. Should be standard C++03 with the `static_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a static *cdecl* function to `pthread_create` as given in this signature:

```
void* handler(void* data);
```

The optional argument can be used to pass your `ClientHandler` object into the thread.

```
class ClientHandler()
{
public:
  static void* handle(void* data);
}

extern "C" {

void* ClientHandler::handle(void* data)
{
  ClientHandler* handler = reinterpret_cast<ClientHandler*>(data)
  // fancy stuff with handler object here
}

} /* extern "C" */
```

Comment: +1 using static member. You can also use `static_cast<ClientHandler*><data)` - I think that's the correct way here. The static handler can call private methods in ClientHandler once it has the pointer.

Comment: @DanS - From an access point of view, the final type of the identifier matters, not the type of the cast. Also, I believe reinterpret cast is more approprate in this example because it reflects the intent of cast ie. recovering a lost type (ClientHandler). A static cast means "try to represent this value in another type, possibly resulting in a different bit pattern".

Comment: @DanS, junjanes: there's an SO question on this very issue: [Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever).

Comment: All C/C++ functions (member or global) are cdecl automatically. You do not need the extern "C" which just marks global functions to have C linkage.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to invoke the method `ClientHandler::handle` from a specific instance of the `ClientHandler` class, it's unfortunately a bit more complicated than your example as pointers to member functions are different than pointers to functions in general. See [here](http://www.tuxtips.org/?p=5) for a complete description of what needs to be done to create pthreads in such a manner.