# Right cast for a void* pointer

Tags: c++, casting

I'm trying to implement a C++ class with a `value` field that can point to anything (a bit like in boost::any). Currently I do the following:

```
class MyClass {
  void* value;
  template<typename T>
  Myclass(const &T v) {
    value = (void*)(new T(v));
  }
};
```

The problem is now to implement a getValue() operation that creates a copy of the inner value with the right type:

```
template<typename T>
T getValue() {
 return *value;
}
```

Here it cannot work because I'm trying to unreference a void* pointer. I was wondering which cast (static_cast? dynamic_cast? other...) I should use such that *value is properly converted into a T object and an exception is thrown if value was not originally of this type?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot dereference a `void*`, it simply makes no sense.  Why not make the class itself generic?  Then you can have:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
  T* value;

  MyClass(const T& v) {
    value = new T(v);
  }

  T getValue() {
    return *value;
  }
};
```

Make sure to create a destructor which deallocates `value` and also to follow [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).  You could also make a version of `getValue` that returns a `const T&` (`const` reference to `T`) to avoid the copy if one is not required.

Comment: I'd like to avoid making the class generic because I need to use STL containers with this class such that I can store objects of different types.

Comment: @sunmat: Well, what you would like and what you can have may be two very different things :).  Your design does not make sense, so throw it out.  Even if it did you would lose all type safety. Perhaps there is a better way to solve the problem at hand. Instead of asking us to solve the last 10% of your proposed solution which makes no sense, how abut describing the high level problem you are trying to solve? There may exist a wholly different approach which you have not considered.

Comment: The application I'm working on reads an XML file containing a list of lines like <parameter name="something" value="42" type="int"/>. These parameters need to be stored somewhere. Eventually, a copy_value("name",address) function is called that is supposed to copy the value of the parameter (if it exists in the XML file) at the specified address. That's all. My current implementation involves a big switch matching the specified type and returning the size of that type to be used in memcpy, I'm just trying to find a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

> which cast (static_cast? dynamic_cast? other...) I should use such that *value is properly converted into a T object

If you must do this conversion, then you should use `static_cast`, which in general is designed to (among other things) reverse any standard conversion. There's a standard conversion from any object pointer type to `void*`, and your getter reverses it, so use the cast designed for that:

```
return *static_cast<T*>(value);
```

You should also either remove the C-style cast from your constructor, or replace that with a `static_cast` too.

A `reinterpret_cast` would also work, but is "overkill". In general you should use the cast that is as restrictive as possible while still performing the conversion you need.

> and an exception is thrown if value was not originally of this type

You are out of luck there - C++ cannot in general tell what the original type of the object was, once you've cast the pointer to `void*`. Your code relies on the caller to call `getValue` with the correct type. For example, consider what happens if the original type was `char` -- that's just one byte in C++, there is no room set aside for any type information that would allow the compiler to check the cast in `getValue`.

`dynamic_cast` does check types in some limited circumstances, but since your template is fully generic, those limited circumstances might not apply.

If you don't like this, you could change your class to store, in addition to the object pointer, a pointer to a `type_info` object (resulting from a use of the `typeid` operator). See the standard header `<typeinfo>`. You could then compare the `type_info` object for the type `T` in the constructor, with the `type_info` object for the type `T` in `getValue`, and throw if they don't match.

As you say, your class is intended to be a bit like `boost::any`, and `getValue` is like `any_cast`. You could consult the source and documentation of that class to see the tricks needed to do what you want. If there were a straightforward way to do it, then `boost::any` would be a straightforward class!

Answer (score 0):

You can't. C++ doesn't provide that sort of mechanism, at least not directly, not for `void*`. A `void*` does not have *any* information that the computer would need to determine what it is, and attempting to "check" if it is a valid whatever-you-cast-it-to is impossible because there aren't particular flags for that.

There are options, though. The first is to use some kind of universal base class, similar to Java's Object, and derive all of your other classes from that. `dynamic_cast` will now work the way you want (returning `NULL` if the object is not a valid object of the class you casted it to).

Another is to simply keep track of what type of object it is yourself. That means augmenting the `void*` with another value that tells you what you need to cast it to.

But really, neither of these things strike me as good ideas. I think there is almost-definitely some other aspect of your design that should be changed rather than using these. Using templates, as @EdS. suggests, is a very good option, for example.

Comment: You can use static_cast<> to cast from void*. Moreover, the committee is going to allow reinterpret_cast<> from and to void* for C++0x

Comment: @djf: Yes, you can use `static_cast` or (later) `reinterpret_cast` -- which explicitly do not provide the kind of safety mechanisms that the question asked for. They just interpret the addressed bits as the requested class, regardless of how much sense that does or doesn't make.