# cannot convert ‘void* (Network::*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’

Tags: c++, void

I'm a beginning C++ programmer and I'm programming on a Linux machine.

I got this error:

```
cannot convert ‘void* (Network::*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)
```

It is comming from this line:

```
pthread_create(&thread_id,0,&Network::SocketHandler, (void*)csock );
```

The function I'm trying to call is:

```
void* Network::SocketHandler(void* lp)
```

I declared both functions in the header file as private.

Do any of you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a *member function pointer* where a regular *function pointer* is expected. A *member function* has an implicit extra parameter: `this`. `pthread_create` does not account for that.

You will have to make the function `static` to be able to use it with `pthread_create`. You can then use the `void*` parameter to pass along what would otherwise be the `this` pointer.

Personally, I would just ditch *pthreads* in favor of *C++11* `std::thread`, or `boost::thread` if you don't have access to a *C++11* implementation.

Comment: Oh you're probably right, he's probably not trying to use it in conjunction with a `Network`. +1

Comment: And use the last parameter of `pthread_create()` to pass the `this` pointer to that `static` method.  Either store the `csock` value as a member of the `Network` class and have the `static` method reach it via the `this` pointer, or else store both values in a dynamically allocated `struct` that the `static` method frees when it is done using it.

Comment: c++11? is it easier/better then pthreads? where can i find some information about threads with c++11? thx

Comment: @user1971401 yes it is much more better, just look up `std::thread` for C++11 on google.

Comment: @SethCarnegie "more bettter" = awesome. (love that phrase).

Comment: @SethCarnegie you almost *have to*.  My contribution to this fiasco: find out more about [C++11 threads here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: If you're not trying to use an instance of `Network` with the function, then K-ballo's answer is what you need. If you are, then read on.**

`pthread_create` expects a normal function to call, and you're trying to use a member function as a non-member function. A member function isn't a normal function because it must have an invoking object.

You can make a function that calls `Network::SocketHandler` on a `Network` and do it that way:

```
void* call_sockethandler(void* nw) {
    Network* network = static_cast<Network*>(nw);

    void* result = network->SocketHandler(somearg);

    // do something w/ result

    return nullptr;
}

Network nw; // this can't go out of scope though
pthread_create(&thread_id, 0, call_sockethandler, &nw);
```

Comment: Why `reinterpret_cast` and not `static_cast` there?

Comment: @K-ballo because I'm dumb.

Comment: I ask because there are valid reasons to `reinterpret_cast` between pointers, but I can never seem to remember them

Comment: @K-ballo according to http://stackoverflow.com/q/310451/726361 `reinterpret_cast` is invalid for casting from `void*` because it's not an object type. I think `reinterpret_cast` is for everything but casting along an inheritance hierarchy, casting away constness, casting between convertible types, and casting from `void*`, but don't quote me on that

Comment: That's odd, under some conditions a `reinterpret_cast` results in two `static_casts` to/from `void*`, I would expected a `reinterpret_cast` from `void*` to be valid... Luckily I never have to resolve to those low level tools!

Comment: +1, nice answer. If the OP is curious about tucking  away the actual thread create in your class, a *basic* sample of how to do it is something [like this](http://ideone.com/pdqLAG). Note, the linked sample only deals with getting the wrapper setup; syncing, joining, etc, are all left to be done, but the proc-routine setup should be evident, which was the goal of the question.