# What does it mean to reinterpret_cast a pointer as long?

Tags: c++

I see this type of code a lot in a project I work on:

```
reinterpret_cast<long>(somePointer)
```

and I don't understand the point of this. It is used for user defined classes usually,
that is, somePointer is pointer to an instance of a user defined class.

Thanks for any help

Comment: see this--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever

Comment: *"I see this type of code a lot in a project I work on:"* -- somebody's project is broken and full of hacks, more likely than not.

Comment: That's bad. Long may not be big enough for a pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's used to convert the address of the pointer to its numeric representation and store it as a `long`.

It's typically used when you need to store a pointer in a particular context where an actual pointer isn't supported. For example, some APIs allow you to pass a numeric key which they will give you back in any callback from that API. You can create an object and cast it to a number and give it to the API. Then in the callback you cast the number back to a pointer with `pointer=reinterpret_cast<type*>(number)` and then access your data.

Comment: @user2381422 At the risk of being pedantic, the size of a pointer could be larger than the size of a long, in which case the value could be truncated, leading to key collisions.

Comment: And it would just explode when read back since the pointer would be invalid if half of it was gone

Comment: @ComeRaczy: Very true, as a matter of fact, if you ever compile that code for windows 64bits, or power 64bit architectures, it's going to break as `sizeof(long)==4, sizeof(void*)==8`. This is not just pedantry, it has practical repercusions in *current* code.

Comment: You need to validate on your platform but it is very likely to work: `$ cat test_pointer_size.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("sizeof(long): %u sizeof(void*): %u\n", sizeof(long), sizeof(void*));
    return 0;
}
$ gcc test_pointer_size.c
$ ./a.out 
sizeof(long): 8 sizeof(void*): 8
`

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is actually nothing more than an integer value, it just that the compiler interprets it as a memory address.

This means that you can store it in an other integer type, if that other integer type is big enough to hold the address (for example, you can't store a 64-bit address in a 16-bit integer variable).

But since C++ considers pointers and normal integer values as distinct and different types, you can't just do a normal cast, you have to ask the compiler to *reinterpret* the pointer as a `long`, which is what `reinterpret_cast` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
reinterpret_cast<long>(somePointer)
```

This piece of code casts the address holded by `somePointer` to a `long`, it's better to use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` for signed/unsigned integral types in C++11 in this. They are capable of holding a value converted from a void pointer and then be converted back to that type with a value that compares equal to the original pointer.

Answer (score 0):

It is, as others have said, converting the pointer to an integer value. This is somewhat "dangerous", as a pointer may not actually fit in a `long`. There is a type in `cstdint` that is called `intptr_t`, which is intended for this purpose.

The `reinterpret_cast<new_type>(value)` really is a "Take the 'bits' of `value` and convert it so that it can be used as `new_type`" - and the compiler will just do what you ask of it, whether it makes much sense or not - so it's up to YOU as a programmer to make sure you only do this in a way that actually does something useful - if you happen to cut of 32 bits from a 64-bit pointer, and then try to make it into a pointer again later on, then it's YOUR fault if the pointer "isn't any good" after. `reinterpret_cast` should really only be used as a last resort, there are often other methods to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast<x>(exp)`

reinterprets the underlying bit pattern, returning a value of type `x`

It instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits of an `exp` as if it had the type `x`

With `reinterpret_cast` you can cast a pointer to a different type, and  then `reinterpret_cast` it back to the original type to get the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sean said, it's useful for manipulating pointers as if they were numbers.

Here's an example from [the MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b.aspx) that uses it to implement a basic hash function (note that this uses an unsigned int rather than a long, but the principle is the same)

```
unsigned short Hash( void *p ) {
   unsigned int val = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>( p );
   return ( unsigned short )( val ^ (val >> 16));
}
```

This takes an arbitrary pointer, and produces an (effectively) unique hash value for that pointer - by treating the pointer as an `unsigned int`, XORing the integral value with a bit-shifted version of itself, and then truncating the result into an `unsigned short`.

However, like everyone else has said, this is very dangerous and should be avoided.