# pass a void pointer to a function with const char * const

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

ok I have a variable

`void * vp`

passed through a function 
`proccessData (void * vp)`

I have a function that accept the following as a parameter

`findIDType(const char* const pointer)` and wanted to pass the pv as `findIDType(pv)`

compiled with GNU 2.95.3

cannot use any other compiler btw.

the issue is that the compiler doesnt give me why it is not acceptable,
it just print out a message `cannot` without any useful description.

how to cast that? from `void*` to `const char* const`

I have tried `(char*)pv`, `(const char*)pv` and `(const char* const)pv` without any luck

Comment: would static cast work?

Comment: Have you tried (const char)pv ? pv is already a pointer.

Comment: please cite all errors and problems with luck you got.\

Comment: Try `findIDType(static_cast<char*>(vp));`

Comment: @RvdK (const char)pv have not been tried, I thought it have to be cast with a pointer because its a pointer.

Comment: @AliAlamiri static cast did not.

Comment: @klm123 I get a small error message just "cannot"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `reinterpret_cast`, and cast to the complete type you would like to pass, this should work:

```
const char* const ptrTpPass = reinterpret_cast<const char* const>(vp);
```

But as mentioned in the comments, `static_cast` would work too and is actually preferable:

```
const char* const ptrTpPass = static_cast<const char* const>(vp);
```

Comment: Prefer `static_cast` when casting some pointer from `void*`. In fact, `reinterpret_cast` is probably not allowed for `void*` in his old compiler. [See this for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever). Also using `static_cast` with the example works fine on my compiler (GCC4.8.1).

Comment: I am recompiling and testing both