# Map a void* back to its original type

Tags: c++, casting, rtti

I am creating a Lua api for my program.
I want to be able to do the following:

```
void* CreateA()
{
     A* a = new A();
     PointerTypes[a] = A;
     return reinterpret_cast<void*>(a);
}

void* CreateB()
{
     B* b = new B();
     PointerTypes[b] = B;
     return reinterpret_cast<void*(b);
}

void DeleteThing( void* p )
{
     typename type = PointerTypes[p];
     type* t = reinterpret_cast< type >( p );
     delete t;
}
```

Is there any straightforward way to do this?
PS: My application already uses RTTI so it can be used here too.

Comment: Briefly, no. Once you've thrown away the type information you can't get it back. So any solution will involve storing type information somewhere.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't use a common base class? (Which is the case if you want to use existing types you can't alter...)

Comment: @leemes The types I am using are completely unrelated. They are components. Some are just simple int*, while some are classes, and to expose them to lua, I use lightuserdata(void*). So using a common base class would be very time-consuming.

Comment: If you're interfacing to Lua, any reasons not to use LuaBind, for example?

Comment: @vines I want to expose a C-style API to lua for simplicity reasons( its meant to be used by people new to programming, and C-style APIs are much easier to understand), and the other features of LuaBind are not worth it for the added dependency on boost(even tough it can be partially avoided).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saving the type in a map (which is not possible because types aren't first class objects in C++) you could store a deleter function in a map. Your factory function then becomes:

```
void* CreateA()
{
    A *a = new A();
    PointerDeleters[a] = [](void *obj) { delete static_cast<A*>(obj); };
    return a;
}
```

or with a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void* Create() // maybe you want to forward c'tor args using variadic template
{
    T *a = new T();
    PointerDeleters[t] = [](void *obj) { delete static_cast<T*>(obj); };
    return t;
}
```

And then invoke it to trigger the deletion of the object `p` with unknown type:

```
void DeleteThing(void* p)
{
    PointerDeleters[p]();
}
```

The map `PointerDeleters` should then have the value type `std::function<void(void*)>`.

A better solution would be (if your design allows it) to use a base class with a virtual destructor; then you can simply delete a pointer to that class without storing any additional information:

```
template<typename T>
BaseClass* Create()
{
    return new T();
}

void DeleteThing(BaseClass* p)
{
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

One question tough: why use `static_cast` and not `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever They allowed to use it in C++11, but it's still considered more dangerous because you can accidentally do more harmful stuff. I prefer `static_cast` unless I have to use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @akaltar this solution so much resembles the actual virtual method call implementation that I would *very seriously* considered refactoring the code to fit available means, rather than reinvent them..

Comment: @vines I am bound by the Lua API and I don't see any better way to do this, without introducing otherwise unneeded code and dependencies everywhere in my code. This is meant to be a core system, and it would affect the whole codebase, so I will stay with this.