# Segfault converting pointers with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

In the following `C++` code, I am attempting to load a function from a shared library.

```
void* tmp = dlsym(dl_lib, symbol);
_fun = reinterpret_cast<plot_sample_fun*>(tmp);
```

However, the `reinterpret_cast` segfaults when converting the pointers. What is wrong here?

Edit:

To provide further context,

```
typedef void plot_sample_fun( const void *, double **, char ***, size_t *);

class Foo {
    void bar(); // Loads _fun as above.

    plot_sample_fun* _fun;
};
```

Comment: You may read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever

Comment: What is _fun? That reinterpret_cast does not do the exception by itself. It only forces compiler to believe that the pointer is of some type. But that segfault is about storing the pointer in some other memory location.

Comment: Is it really the `reinterpret_cast` that segfaults, not a later use of the pointer? And why aren't you checking that it's not null?

Comment: There is no chance that the cast is causing the segfault, as it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: AlexanderVX is correct, storing values into the class member _fun is causing the segfaults.

Comment: Even something as simple as this->_fun = NULL segfaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer physically is just an integer variable that contains some address.

The reinterpret_cast is just a trick to make compiler believe that the pointer is of certain type.

In the code sample above the only possibility of segfault either first line but the author says second, or the second line and the reason is _fun is some kind of dangled reference so it writes to an incorrect memory location.

After the author updated us on the pointer type it is clearer that the correct code should look like:

```
typedef void (plot_sample_fun*)( const void *, double **, char ***, size_t *);
```

Also the assignment:

```
_fun = reinterpret_cast<plot_sample_fun>(tmp);
```

And the class member declaration should not have asterisk *

```
plot_sample_fun _fun;
```

And if that does not help then we wonder if the instance of class that contains _fun is allocated correctly and not released yet.

Comment: Your latter explanation is promising, but how can I fix this dangling reference? I've updated my question with more context.

Comment: Eric, please let us know what _fun variable is.

Comment: It is of the type in the typedef plot_sample_fun.

Comment: So, it seems like the function pointer type was declared a bit non-standard way plus there is no need to cast to pointer of that type when the type is correct. That'd be interesting to see the disassembler from your original binary code.

Comment: Nope, the instance of the class was the culprit. It wasn't allocated correctly!

Comment: Nothing weird then. The second version about dangling pointer was right.

Answer (score 2):

The `reinterpret_cast` itself can't segfault, since it only changes the type of the expression for the compiler. **It gets compiled away and doesn't do anything at runtime** (unlike for example `dynamic_cast`).

What is failing is your use of the pointer later in the program.

> Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, **the reinterpret_cast expression does not compile to any CPU instructions**

- quote from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

I recommend compiling the program with debugging turned on (`-g` with gcc/clang) and then running it in a debugger, to see what is actually failing.