# Cast void* to array of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct, casting

I have a vector of RGB data.

```
vector<int> image({1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3 , 4,4,4});
```

I want to flip this image horizontally (about the center column).

to perform flip operation, I have created a function

```
flip(void* image, int rows, int cols)
```

where i would like to perform flip, but keep individual triplets of RGB intact

So I created a

```
struct color{
    char r;
    char g;
    char b;
};
```

and calling the function as

```
int main(){
vector<int> image({1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3 , 4,4,4});
flip(&image[0],rows,cols);
}
```

but casting void* to struct color[] raises compilation error. 
How can I proceed around this ?

Comment: Why are you using void pointers?

Comment: Can you include the casting statement?

Comment: If you really really really really have to go the `void *` way, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever).

Comment: i tried using std::copy but seems complex.

Comment: @devil0150   `struct color image[] = ((struct color[])arr);`

Comment: vector<int> is a class, not a C char array. Also in c++ you need to make an explicit cast

Comment: Also why not just using vector<int[3]>

Comment: What does the void* point to? the vector?

Comment: why not vector<color> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast to an array in C++. You'll have to use a pointer.

```
struct color* image = (struct color*)arr;
```

And for your purposes, this won't work right away. You'll have to start using a vector of `char` not `int`. This is because and `int` is usually 4 bytes and a char is 1 byte. Trying to assign an `int` to your struct (which is 3 bytes) wouldn't give you the result you expect.

Then you can access the pointer as an array. For example `image[0].r` would return the first value in the vector, and `image[1].r` would return the fourth. Just be careful to not go beyond the size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

i changed the struct as

```
struct color{
int rgb[3];
};
```

and

```
struct color* image = (struct color*)arr;
```

provides an array of struct color which can be flipped keeping the rgb data intact.