# What is the best way to compare uintptr_t and a pointer type?

Tags: c++, comparison

Is it just the reinterpret_cast?

```
int *pointer;
uintptr_t value;
value == reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(pointer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on your goal really.

> **[expr.reinterpret.cast]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#4) A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type
>   large enough to hold it. The mapping function is
>   implementation-defined. [ Note: It is intended to be unsurprising to
>   those who know the addressing structure of the underlying machine.
>    — end note ] A value of type `std​::​nullptr_­t` can be converted to an
>   integral type; the conversion has the same meaning and validity as a
>   conversion of `(void*)0` to the integral type.
>
> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#5) A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly
>   converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of
>   sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to
>   the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between
>   pointers and integers are otherwise implementation-defined.

The mapping is implementation defined (obviously). If you wish to check that the value of `pointer` was used to initialize `value`, then your check is insufficient. The above doesn't promise that `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(pointer)` will always yield the same integer, even though all sane implementations today do.

I would do the check in reverse, since we have a round trip guarantee:

```
reinterpret_cast<int*>(value) == pointer;
```

But even then, it's a pretty weak guarantee. I would not faff about with these conversions too much if I were you. It may be worth to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the standard to the letter, you ought to use

```
value == (uintptr_t)(void*)pointer
```

or using `reinterpret_cast`:

```
value == reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(pointer))
```

which personally I find less readable. Naturally the compiler will remove all the "fluff".

Comment: Thanks! Do we really need reinterpret_cast<void*>(pointer) and not just static_cast<void*>(pointer)?

Comment: @embedc: I'd plump for `reinterpret_cast` as it's more descriptive of what you're doing. But even better is to use the c-style cast. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever, even though the cast is the other way round in that question, but the answers are comprehensive.

Comment: Well, the C++ standard defers to another standard for this :P https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20.1.4