# Make a copy of a pointer passed to template function

Tags: c++

I have the following lines in my main function.

```
BlackScholesPricer* option = new EuropeanCallOption(105, 100, 0.5, 0.1, 0.36, 0);
PricingUtil::mesh_pricer<EuropeanCallOption>(option, 105, 150, 5);
```

Here is the function in question.

```
template <typename OptionType>
std::vector<double> PricingUtil::mesh_pricer(BlackScholesPricer* option, 
std::size_t lower_bound, std::size_t upper_bound, std::size_t mesh_size) {

OptionType financial_instrument(*option);
std::vector<double> generated_prices;

for (std::size_t price = lower_bound; price <= upper_bound; price += mesh_size) {

    financial_instrument.asset_price(price);
    generated_prices.push_back(financial_instrument.price());

}

return generated_prices;

}
```

I want to pass a derived class BlackScholesPricer to the function but I don't want to modify the object I pass to the function so I'm trying to create a copy of it. I'm getting an error stating that an object of type BlackScholes* cannot be converted to const EuropeanCallOption& (This is from the copy constructor I suppose).

What's the most efficient way of solving the problem, or even better yet, what's the best approach to take in this type of situation other than mine?

Comment: Note: Copying a pointer is *not* the same as copying the object the pointer *points to*.

Comment: Write a virtual `clone` function and have it return a copy.  Then you can call it polymorphicly and just get the right thing.

Comment: what is the relationship between `BlackScholesPricer`, `EuropeanCallOption`?

Comment: @AdamZahran `EuropeanCallOption` is a derived class of `BlackScholesPricer`

Comment: Why do you even need to create `OptionType financial_instrument`? Why not just use the `BlackScholesPricer* option` directly?

Comment: write a custom copy constructor which will create deep copy of object

Comment: @Kevin Because I don't want to modify the object the user passes in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a template function you have several possibilities before you rush to implement a polymorphic clone method:

### Casting

```
template <typename OptionType>
std::vector<double> PricingUtil::mesh_pricer(BlackScholesPricer* option, 
std::size_t lower_bound, std::size_t upper_bound, std::size_t mesh_size) {

    // note: it seems that you are sure that this is the actual type 

    OptionType financial_instrument(*static_cast<OptionType*>(option));

    // your code goes here ...

}
```

### Using the template parameter on your argument

```
template <typename OptionType>
std::vector<double> PricingUtil::mesh_pricer(OptionType* option, 
std::size_t lower_bound, std::size_t upper_bound, std::size_t mesh_size) {

    OptionType financial_instrument(*option);

    // your code goes here ...

}
```

### Using the template parameter on your argument and let the compiler make the copy for you

```
template <typename OptionType>
std::vector<double> PricingUtil::mesh_pricer(OptionType option, 
std::size_t lower_bound, std::size_t upper_bound, std::size_t mesh_size) {

    // your code goes here using option safely - it is a copy...
    // of course you need to call the method a bit differently
    // with a reference and not a pointer as first param

}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast/1255015#1255015 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever