# Specifying void* parameter in derived function

Tags: c++, inheritance, void-pointers

I would like to do something that probably is not possible in Cpp, but I could not find a post about this specifically.

I want to have a derived class specify the type of a void* parameter on a virtual function.

I have a base class called interface with a send function.

```
// pure virtual
class Interface{
    virtual bool Send(const void*)=0;

};

struct Packet{
    DataType data;
};

class SpecificInterface{
     bool Send(const DataType*);
}
```

Is there a way to make something like this work? The intent is that SpecificInterface::Send implements Interface::Send. Allowing SpecificInterface to not be a pure virtual while restricting the void* to a specific packet type.

Otherwise I know I could take a void* parameter and static_cast it into the Packet* type; however, I do not want others to send a pointer type that cannot be cast to Packet*.

Let me know if this is not clear

Comment: No, it can't work this way. Assume you have some `SpecificInterface& foo` and want to call `Send`. How should the compiler know what class `foo` actually points? When implementing an interface you can't just change the signature or functionality of the interface, that would defy the point of having interfaces.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that a `SpecificInterface` is still an `Interface`, and anything that an `Interface` can send must also be something that a `SpecificInterface` can send. See the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @AdrianMole yes thanks

Comment: @alterigel That is a good point maybe if I need this level of specification then SpecificInterface is not really an Interface. Or at least in the way I have defined Interface.

Comment: What should happen if we do `Interface& i = something(); int x = 5; i.send(&x);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@RSahu is correct, of course. You could still use a virtual method to do about the same thing:

```
class Interface {
    virtual bool send(const void*) = 0;
};

struct Packet {
    DataType data;
};

class SpecificInterface {
    bool send(cont void*) override { 
        send(static_cast<DataType*>(data));
    }
    bool send(cont DataType*); // code which actually does something
};
```

However - I recommend *against* your whole approach to begin with - it is massively unsafe, since the validity of the type is never checked! It's a source of many potential bugs. More often than not, you can avoid doing this. Here are a few things you might try instead:

1. [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) - a class which doesn't offer you compile-time type safety, but at least checks types at run-time. You would have a `send(const std::any& data)` virtual function, and inside it you would call `std::any_cast<DataType>(data)` to get a `DataType` or `std::any_cast<DataType>(&data)` to get a `DataType *`.
2. Probably even better - the [Curiously-recurring template pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) (CRTP):

   ```
   template <typename T>
   class Interface {
        virtual bool send(T*) = 0;
   }; 

   class SpecificInterface : Interface<DataType> {
       bool send(cont DataType*) override;
   }
   ```

Comment: I think this CRTP convey's the use case intent the best.

Comment: @Czarking: Oh, and, by the way - consider sending `const& T` or `std::span<T>` rather than `T*`.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to override a `virtual` function, the number of arguments and the types of the arguments must exactly match the declaration in the base class. You'll have to use:

```
class SpecificInterface{
     bool Send(const void* ptr)
     {
        cont DataType* dataTypePtr = static_cast<const DataType*>(ptr);
        // Now use dataTypePtr any way you wish
     }
};
```

Please note that use of such code is dangerous. If `ptr` does not really point to a `DataType` object, your program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: My understanding was something like this being better.  The downside being the crash if ptr is not the right type. Are you saying reinterpret is better because I have a chance to handle the memory in case of wrong pointer type? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/should-i-use-static-cast-or-reinterpret-cast-when-casting-a-void-to-whatever

Comment: @Czarking, no, I am not saying that. `reinterpret_cast` is a coercion. If `ptr` does not point to a `DataType` object, your program will most likely crash and burn.

Comment: Ok why not use static_cast then?

Comment: @Czarking, You can. When it comes to casting a `void*`, neither `static_cast` nor `reinterpret_cast` provide any safefy. You are on your own at that point.