# Translate UniGui Delphi code to C++Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, types, c++builder

How can I translate this code into C++? UniGui component.

```pascal
v﻿ar
  FrmList : TList;
  I : Integer;
  Frm : TUniBaseForm;
begin
  FrmList := UniSession.FormsList;

  UniListBox1.Clear;
  for I := 0 to FrmList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Frm := FrmList[I];
    UniListBox1.Items.Add(Frm.Name + ' ' + Frm.ClassName  );
  end;
```

I have a problem with `Frm := FrmList[i];`. I have tried:

`frm = UniSession->FormsList->Items[i];`

> E2034 Cannot convert 'void *' to 'TUniBaseForm *'

`frm = dynamic_cast<TUniBaseForm*>(UniSession->FormsList->Items[i]);`

> E2307 Type 'void' is not a defined class with virtual functions

`frm = dynamic_cast<TUniBaseForm*>(UniSession->FormsList[i]);`

> E2031 Cannot cast from 'TList' to 'TUniBaseForm *'

Comment: `(void *) frm = ...` ? Or C does not allow datatyping LValues?  Also, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi allows an untyped pointer (`void*` in C++) to be assigned to another typed pointer without a cast. C++ does not, you need an explicit cast.

You were on the right track with your 2nd attempt, but you need to use either `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`, instead of `dynamic_cast`, eg:

```cpp
TUniBaseForm *Frm = static_cast<TUniBaseForm*>(FrmList->Items[i]);
```

or

```cpp
TUniBaseForm *Frm = reinterpret_cast<TUniBaseForm*>(FrmList->Items[i]);
```

See these related questions:

[Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/)

[When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/)