# How to access variable of an object from within an other object stored in void pointer

Tags: c++, class, void-pointers

I have to make a dynamic array in a class and store another class' object in that array. Then use the array to access the other classes. there are a total of 3 classes to be stored in that same array.

But when I try to access the var, it wont allow me to... (obj.arr[0].a;) This one. I tried many ways but cant find any solution. please help.

Code:

```
class T1
{
public:
    int a = 1;
};

class T2
{
public:
    int a = 2;
};


class T
{
public:
    void *arr[];
};

int main()
{

    T obj;

    obj.arr[0] = new T1;
    obj.arr[1] = new T2;

    obj.arr[0].a;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `void*`'s.  Once you do that conversion, you don't know what it pointed to anymore.  Looks like you might need a `std::variant` or `std::any`.

Comment: I have to make the array inside a custom-built class.
I can not use system-built classes like std::variant or std::any

your response was much appriciated.

Comment: *"I can not use system-built classes like..."* - because ? I mean, *I* can't because my org isn't yet up to using a C++17 compliant toolchain, and doesn't allow using `boost`. but, out of curiosity, why can't you ?

Comment: @muhammadomerirfan In that case, you'll need to build your own tagged union (basically what `std::variant` is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not want to let you, because a `void*` has no member named `a`. You have to let the compiler know that you want to pretend the `void*` is actually a `T1*`.

That being said, this is a terrible practice. One of the advantages of c++ over c is that it provides a way of avoiding the need to force-polymorphism like this. A much better way would be to make all classes inherit a common base class (and instead of void pointers, use pointers to that base class in your array). If virtual methods satisfy your needs, use those, otherwise use `dynamic_cast` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to retrieve the whole objects.

If you still insist on retrieving the object from the `void*`, do so using `static_cast`, and triple-check that you have actually put the object under that pointer.

```
static_cast<T1*>(&obj.arr[0])->a;
```

Your `void*[]`'s size is also not initialized, but I assume that is only for simplicity?

Comment: [Should I use static_cast or reinterpret_cast when casting a void* to whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310451/)

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are attempting, you would need an explicit type-cast of each array element, eg:

```cpp
class T1
{
public:
    int a = 1;
};

class T2
{
public:
    int a = 2;
};


class T
{
public:
    void **arr;
};

int main()
{
    T obj;

    obj.arr = new void*[2];
    obj.arr[0] = new T1;
    obj.arr[1] = new T2;

    static_cast<T1*>(obj.arr[0])->a;
    static_cast<T2*>(obj.arr[1])->a;

    ...

    delete static_cast<T1*>(obj.arr[0]);
    delete static_cast<T2*> obj.arr[1];
    delete[] obj.arr;
}
```

However, that begs the question - how do you know which type to cast each element to?  You could do something like this:

```cpp
enum Ttype {typT1, typT2};

class TBase
{
    Ttype type;
    TBase(Ttype type) : type(type) {}
    virtual ~TBase() {}
};

class T1 : public TBase
{
public:
    int a = 1;
    T1() : TBase(typT1) {}
};

class T2 : public TBase
{
public:
    int a = 2;
    T2() : TBase(typT2) {}
};


class T
{
public:
    void **arr;
};

int main()
{
    T obj;

    obj.arr = new void*[2];
    obj.arr[0] = static_cast<TBase*>(new T1);
    obj.arr[1] = static_cast<TBase*>(new T2);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        TBase *tb = static_cast<TBase*>(obj.arr[i]);
        switch (tb->type) {
            case typT1:
                static_cast<T1*>(tb)->a;
                break;
            case typT2:
                static_cast<T2*>(tb)->a;
                break;
        }
    }

    ...

    delete static_cast<TBase*>(obj.arr[0]);
    delete static_cast<TBase*>(obj.arr[1]);
    delete[] obj.arr;
}
```

But that is ugly, and gets tedious to maintain over time as more classes are added.

You should move the common `a` member into the base class, and get rid of the `void*` altogether.  No need for casts, let polymorphism work for you:

```cpp
class TBase
{
    int a;
    TBase(int a) : a(a) {}
    virtual ~TBase() {}
};

class T1 : public TBase
{
public:
    T1() : TBase(1) {}
};

class T2 : public TBase
{
public:
    T2() : TBase(2) {}
};


class T
{
public:
    TBase **arr;
};

int main()
{
    T obj;

    obj.arr = new TBase*[2];
    obj.arr[0] = new T1;
    obj.arr[1] = new T2;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        obj.arr[i]->a;
    }

    ...

    delete obj.arr[0];
    delete obj.arr[1];
    delete[] obj.arr;
}
```